# If a div is focused then have the click even on other .class

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to have something like this that is a div with class is on focus then there should be an click event on the other class . is this possible ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="focusDiv">
  <div class="clickEvent">

  </div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.focus:focus{
 background: #fff;
 border-color: #fa9a34;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(250, 154, 52, .5);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(250, 154, 52, .8);
 outline: none; /* remove outline */
   }
```

I just wanted to know if possible then how ?

Comment: If the parent `div` element is focused (*how?*) you want to trigger, or bind, a click event, or handler?

Answer (score 0):

Use [.mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

```
$('div').mouseenter(function(){ 
   $('div.className').click();
               or
   $('div.className').trigger('click');
});
```

[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what exactly you mean, but the question is tagged as jQuery, so I will give my best attempt at answering it.

```
$('.focusDiv').focus(function() { 
    $('.clickEvent').trigger('click'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible, if only you have the latest version of `jQuery` included in the scripts section of the `head`. :)

You can have `trigger` for that. Use it like this:

```
$('element').focus(function () { // when element is in focus
   $('element').trigger('click'); // click on second element
});
```

This way you will create the click event on the other div once the click occurs on the first element!

**Edit:** Sorry I wrote `click` instead of `focus` mistakenly.